# django 1.6 password reset issues

Tags: django

I am having a problem with password reset on a django 1.6 site. urls.py has:

```
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$',
   'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm',
   name='password_reset_confirm'
```

And when I click on the `Reset my password` link I get:

```
NoReverseMatch at /user/password/reset/
Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb36': 'Mw', u'token': u'4bs-b5728359cb279d542120'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$']
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in password_reset
  158.             form.save(**opts)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in save
  256.             email = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, c)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  164.         return t.render(Context(dictionary))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_node
  854.         return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  447.                         six.reraise(*exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  433.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=context.current_app)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  536.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  456.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /user/password/reset/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb36': 'Mw', u'token': u'4bs-b5728359cb279d542120'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$']
```

Comment: Have you looked at the django 1.6 source around this functionality it gives you examples of the regexs django is using to validate the urls. https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6.11/django/contrib/auth/urls.py#L16

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django-nonrel + Django-registration problem: unexpected keyword argument 'uidb36' when resetting password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323852/django-nonrel-django-registration-problem-unexpected-keyword-argument-uidb36)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the regexp, nor is it the same as that other question. The issue seems to be that part is in `uidb36` and part is in `uidb64`

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Question updated with traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your first problem: (which you've now fixed in the question)

You need to update the regex to include `_\-`, as well as changing the name `uidb36` to `uidb64`. It should be:

```
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$',
    'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm',
    name='password_reset_confirm'
),
```

### Your second problem:

You need to update your `registration/password_reset_email.html` email template to use `uidb64` instead of `uidb36`. The example email template [given in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset) is:

```
Someone asked for password reset for email {{ email }}. Follow the link below:
{{ protocol}}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

This is all covered in the [Django 1.6 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset).

Comment: Yes, I have it as `uidb64`. The issue is as I said in my original post, that it's failing with `Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb36': 'Mw', u'token': u'4bs-bd0dd5db5e44f6a33c5e'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['password_reset_confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$']`

Comment: You're not reading my answer or the release notes carefully enough. You have `(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z])`. It should be `(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-])`.

Comment: I made that change. I now have `url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', name='password_reset_confirm'` but the error I am getting has `uidb36` This is the error I get now: `NoReverseMatch at /user/password/reset/
Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb36': 'Mw', u'token': u'4bs-b5728359cb279d542120'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$']`

Comment: Try generating a new password reset link and see if that works. If that doesn't work, please update your question with the full traceback.

Comment: Thanks. Once I fixed `registration/password_reset_email.html` it works.