# NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password/reset/ django registration redux

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use django-registration-redux for my authentication in my project, but when testing out the password reset, I come up with an error containing the following traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /accounts/password/reset/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 418, in dispatch
    return super(PasswordResetView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 183, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 431, in form_valid
    form.save(**opts)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 289, in save
    email, html_email_template_name=html_email_template_name,
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 236, in send_mail
    body = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 40, in render
    output = self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 63, in render
    result = self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 458, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 91, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 497, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
[07/Feb/2018 22:33:51] "POST /accounts/password/reset/ HTTP/1.1" 500 197836
[2018-02-07 22:33:51,527] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 45428)

Internal Server Error: /accounts/password/reset/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 418, in dispatch
    return super(PasswordResetView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 183, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 431, in form_valid
    form.save(**opts)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 289, in save
    email, html_email_template_name=html_email_template_name,
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 236, in send_mail
    body = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 40, in render
    output = self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 63, in render
    result = self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 458, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 91, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 497, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
[07/Feb/2018 22:33:52] "POST /accounts/password/reset/ HTTP/1.1" 500 197836
```

My registration, login and other django-registration functions are working but this still gives an error. I have checked other SO related questions but none of them has helped me thus far. Below is my project's urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from sweet import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    # url(r'^lollipop/', include('lollipop.urls')),
    # url(r'^pinpop/', include('pinpop.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('sweet.urls')),   
    # url(r'^', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

EDIT:
After following BUZZY's answer, here is the new traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 418, in dispatch
    return super(PasswordResetView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 183, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 431, in form_valid
    form.save(**opts)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 289, in save
    email, html_email_template_name=html_email_template_name,
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 236, in send_mail
    body = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 40, in render
    output = self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 63, in render
    result = self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 458, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 91, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 497, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with keyword arguments '{u'uidb36': 'MjY', u'token': u'4ti-05f34bb12daa049f844d'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$']
[07/Feb/2018 22:57:25] "POST /accounts/password/reset/ HTTP/1.1" 500 201717.
```

Still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the view with the name `password_reset_confirm` hasn't been found.

It's in the auth app, so try adding:

```
url(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
```

to your urlpatterns.

Comment: It's still not working. See the updated traceback in the question edit

Comment: Now it found the pattern, but the arguments didn't match it. For some reason you have `uidb36` instead of `uidb64` as an argument. Unfortunately it's hard to guess what actually happened without the code.

Comment: Probably some problem with the version. Maybe that will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323852/django-nonrel-django-registration-problem-unexpected-keyword-argument-uidb36

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I changed uidb36 to uidb64 in my template and it worked